# Filter in ng-repeat not applying

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, filtering

I'm working on a Ionic project which has a view that shows a scrollable list with a search input that filters the displayed results, this view is located in a template that is loaded into another view.

We noticed the search input would move with the content when the scrolling began, disappearing making it a problem when you had scrolled and wish to filter the results.

I tried to workaround this by pulling the search input outside the template and placing it above where it is loaded in the parent view.

While this renders the search input at a fixed location, even though I specified the controller that handles its logic, the filter isn't applied on the list.

Here is how my code looks on the parent view:

```
<ion-popover-view id="popfecha" class="fit" >

<ion-view view-title="Nuevo ReSAT">
  <ion-content class="padding" data-ng-hide="activity.state.notes || activity.state.reasonShow || activity.state.product_lineShow || activity.state.account || activity.state.contact " >

    <form name="form" data-ng-submit="submitForm()">
       <!-- A long form -->
    </form>

  </ion-content>

  <ion-view class="wrapper" data-ng-show="activity.state.account" >
    <!-- Filter section -->

    <div data-ng-controller="AccountCatalogueCtrl" class="item item-input filterSearch bar-header popupBorder borderFirstItemPopup">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control"
               ng-model="filterText.name">
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- ./Filter section  -->

    <ion-content class="padding" data-ng-show="activity.state.account" >
      <div data-ng-controller="AccountCatalogueCtrl" ng-include="'templates/account-catalogue.html'"></div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>

  <ion-content class="padding" data-ng-show="activity.state.notes" >
    <div data-ng-controller="ActivityNotesCtrl" ng-include="'templates/activity-notes.html'"></div>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-content class="padding" data-ng-show="activity.state.reasonShow" >
    <div data-ng-controller="ReasonCatalogueCtrl" ng-include="'templates/reason-catalogue.html'"></div>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-content class="padding" data-ng-show="activity.state.product_lineShow" >
    <div data-ng-controller="ProductLineCatalogueCtrl" ng-include="'templates/product-line-catalogue.html'"></div>
  </ion-content>

  <ion-content class="padding" data-ng-show="activity.state.contact" >
    <div data-ng-controller="ContactCatalogueCtrl" ng-include="'templates/contact-catalogue.html'"></div>
  </ion-content>


</ion-view>

</ion-popover-view>
```

As you can see, I'm specifying the controller `AccountCatalogueCtrl` to the div that holds the search input and to the div that loads the template `account-catalogue.html`.

Here's my template:

```
<ion-list>

    <ion-radio class="item-avatar popupBorder borderLastItemPopupIterator whiteBackground" ng-repeat="acc in accountCatalogue | orderBy:'-name' : true | filter:filterText track by acc._id"
              type="item-text-wrap" ng-value="acc.name" ng-if="!acc.isDivider" ng-click="select(acc); go()" >
      <img src="img/account.png">

      <h2>{{acc.name}}</h2>

    </ion-radio>

</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll
  ng-if="canLoadAccounts"
  on-infinite="loadAccounts()"
  distance="5%">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

I even placed a watch on the filterText object to see it was being updated, the watch did show me that the property name was changing.

This is my controller:

```
var mod = angular.module('starter.controllers');

mod.controller('AccountCatalogueCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
  $scope.select = function(acct){

    $rootScope.activity.accountId = acct._id;

  };

  $scope.go = function ( ) {

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.$emit('HideAccount');
    },150);

  };
  // Added the lines below to see if the filter was changing
  // Since in the beginning filterText doesn't exist undefined is returned
  // Later when a value is placed in the input then the filterText object is created    
  $scope.$watch('filterText.name', function(n, o){
    console.log('filter updated ' + JSON.stringify(n) + ' ' + JSON.stringify(o));
  });
}]);
```

If I place the search input inside my template, the filter is applied, but when placed outside the filter isn't applied. Am I doing something wrong in my implementation? How can I make sure the filter applies even if the component that received it is outside the template that makes use of the filter?

Comment: If you have two divs with ng-controller="AccountCatalogueCtrl", they will each have their own, separate **instance** of the controller, each with a separate $scope. You need a shared service between the controllers. services are singletons. Controllers are not.

Comment: is there a way to wrap two components in the same controller? or some sort of inheritance?

Comment: Directives can access the controller or scope of its parent. But to share data across controllers you need to use a factory, service, or provider.

Comment: I just found out if a component A with a controller X assigned is inside another component B with a different controller Y, the variables from the scope on controller X will be available for the view for component B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing the controller from the search input, so it looked like this:

```
<!-- Filter section -->

<div class="item item-input filterSearch bar-header popupBorder borderFirstItemPopup">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control"
           ng-model="filterText.name">
  </label>
</div>
<!-- ./Filter section  -->
```

I saw that I could access to filterText on my controller AccountCatalogueCtrl due to the component that shows the catalogue has access to the scope variables from the parent component that it is holding it. This way I could change the value outside AccountCatalogueCtrl and affect the filter inside the list.